# NSURL Bad Excess

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url, nsurl

I have got the `error 1000 (URL bad excess)` and I'm unsure what happened. The sample URL roughly looks like this (which already has the percentage encoded as I read from [Bad URL when requesting with NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287230/bad-url-when-requesting-with-nsurl)):

```
http://test1.test.com/X?op=find&base=tpl01&request=%28%28WCL=DVD%20or%20WCL=VCD%20or%20WCL=SDVD%29%20AND%20%28WFM=VM%29%20AND%20%28WIS=19%20or%20WIS=01%29%29
```

However, I am still not sure why does it not work.

If needed (before the percentage encoding):

```
http://test1.test.com/X?op=find&bas=tp01&request=((WCL=DVD or WCL=VCD or WCL=SDVD) AND (WFM=VM) AND (WIS=19 or WIS=01))
```

In my internet connection I had already logged the `request.URL` but it just appeared to be nulled. I did insert my URL. Would be thankful for help in any way.

Comment: I think we'll need to see some of the code around creating the NSURL.

Comment: Also, have you allowed access for your iPhone's IP address in Aleph's `server_ip_allowed` configuration file. If you are writing an app for general release it is a really bad idea to allow the clients to talk directly to the X-Server, I would proxy the requests through an intermediate web service to protect your Aleph instance from malicious requests.

Comment: @Sahara have the issue been resolved..

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** The encoding type **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding** might solve your problem

```
NSString* urlText = @"http://test1.test.com/X?op=find&bas=tp01&request=((WCL=DVD or WCL=VCD or WCL=SDVD) AND (WFM=VM) AND (WIS=19 or WIS=01))";
urlText = [urlText stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlText];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                   timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

    NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;


NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: given url has no response at all

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is particularly helpful. I believe the OP has changed the host name of his server in the question. He even says "The sample URL roughly looks like this" which implies that the URL he posted is not the actual URL.

Comment: @Prince yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I changed the host name. Pardon me, as I'm in a difficult position to disclose the url. The normal URL is working but only when i use the app to fetch the data using the URL, then it returns a NULL value in the request.URL

Comment: @Vimal Venugopalan Thanks for the answer given.. But my URL is required to load data.. And my load data only takes in String.. Is there any other way to this??

Comment: @VimalVenugopalan Hey!! I solved my issue already! Some minor mistake i did.. Anyways thanks for the effort though~

Comment: happy to know you figured it out.. can you accept my answer.. if it has helped you solve your problem in any which way