# Getting Google Map direction issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, xcode4.5

I am working on Google Maps in Google maps how to represent the driving directions to the  user with Way points in rout. According to the Google map SDK they have give an example url i tried with that but i was not able get the json response.

url : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

Error :  Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x9245e00 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8643f00 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad URL when requesting with NSURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287230/bad-url-when-requesting-with-nsurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do the following

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[@" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```