# Generating a URL string for NSURLRequest fails to initiate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, http, url

This one has me pretty confused. If I put in the following:

```
NSString *LoginURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=13242134"];
//NSLog output:  http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=2314084
```

And use this in a URL request, it works fine, but I need to make this dynamic, so I have it concatenate the URL string with a new UserID by using the following:

```
NSString *user = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"CustomerID"]];

//user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CustomerID"];

NSString *LoginURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=%@", user];
//NSLog output:  http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=2314084
```

Here is the rest of my request initializer:

```
 NSString *urlString = LoginURLString;
responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And the other methods that handle the request:

```
   -(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    //   [connection release];

    CommonPickUpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    CommonLocationInfoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
}
```

This request never even starts. I really don't understand why. I have tried to output the two strings to the NSLog and either way they look exactly the same. Can anyone explain? Thanks for your help!

Edit: The Connection `didFailWithError` method is outputting this:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0xf6a6f50 {NSUnderlyingError=0xf6a75d0 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}

Output from answer 1:

2012-05-08 13:45:24.959 AmericanTaxi[1295:707] Connection failed with error: bad URL
2012-05-08 13:45:24.960 AmericanTaxi[1295:707] for the URL: (null)

Output of urlString and LoginURLString:

2012-05-08 13:57:40.415 AmericanTaxi[1320:707] LoginURLString: http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=2314084

2012-05-08 13:57:40.417 AmericanTaxi[1320:707] urlstring: http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=2314084

Comment: What's the type of the customerId ? (integer or strings)

Comment: What if you you do `NSLog(@"%@", LoginURLString)`? Are you sure that the CustomerID is really in the user's prefs?

Comment: its initial object is a  NSString (when its added to the UserDefaults)

Comment: post the NSLog output for both

Comment: if I do that NSLog outputs: http://dispatch.americantaxi.com:8080/AT/servlet/OnlineOrderServices?command=retrieveCustomerCommonPlaces&customerId=2314084

Comment: Pst it to the original question. It gets truncated in the comments.

Comment: Are you starting the NSURL request in the same code block/method? One issue could be that your string is going out of scope since it is only declared locally and not retained.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the NSLog Outputs

Comment: Yes, the request is initiated in the same method.

Comment: If the request doesn't start, there is something else going on. You'll need to post more code to see where the issue is.

Comment: Again I have updated to show all of the URL request code

Comment: Did you implement didFailWithError? My guess is it is actually starting and going there. Put a NSLog is every NSURLConnection delegate method (including didFailWithError) and see what is really going on. Also, the logs you posted can't be correct since the customer number in the first string is different than in the log output.

Comment: @Joel I have now tried that and I see it is giving a error, but still not sure how to resolve it. I have posted it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your didFailWithError, check the URL and see why it is bad by adding this to your didFailWithError delegate:

```
NSLog(@"Connection failed with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
NSLog(@"for the URL: %@", [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
```

Post the result.

Comment: I've posted at the bottom of the question, the address is null... strange why would that be?

Comment: Well, that's no good. There's your problem. My guess is that LoginURLString is going out of scope before you assign it to urlString? Log the urlString right before you create the request, and the LoginURLString right before you assign it to urlString. By the way, why even bother creating the urlString variable? You can just use LoginURLString when you create the request.

Comment: both strings look ok if I do that, I'll post above

Comment: also I did try and remove the line assigning urlstring to LoginURLString and just shooting the request to LoginURLString, but the results are the same.

Comment: try escaping the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162653/ios-develoment-why-is-my-nsurlconnection-failing-with-a-bad-url-error-for-onl